# Header and Footer options in pages and posts

Tags: posts, pages, footer, custom-header

I wanted to add a custom option to select header and footer in every pages and post. I have two headers and two footers so I wanted to select every page. So please suggest me how can I possibly?

Comment: and why can't you write this code yourself, or copy it from some free theme?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by Using template page as well as custom fields. Let us say your custom fields value are 1 and 2 for header your conditions will  be.

```
if($header==1)
{
 get_header(1);
}
else
{get_header();}
```

And similarly for footer it will be

```
if($footer==1)
    {
     get_footer(1);
    }
    else
    {
      get_footer();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I know. but I wanted to select a customer to changes page wise header and footer.

Comment: Do you mean to make changes from frontend?

Comment: I have three-four header and footers so I want to give options to the client as per pages.

Comment: can you show me an example what do you need exactly.

Comment: Same as client select header check screen shot: https://prnt.sc/ggu0bp

Comment: In this it will be easy if you can call custom header and footers in page template.

Comment: How can I call custom header and footer?

Comment: I mean to say you can add diffferent templates with different header and Footer over there. So admin user can select template as per his choice

Comment: Yes, I know but I want the option in the backend. if you know then tell me.